# My MacBook connects to my TV through Airplay by itself, all the time

Tags: macos, mac, display, screen, airplay

My Macbook Pro M1, keeps on connecting to my TV through Airplay, without my consent. I have used Airplay to display on my TV in the past, for specific reasons, but I don't want for it to do it by itself. It keeps on turning on my TV, and it's annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you have set it up for Screen Mirroring..? The look of this might depend on the macOS version.

[image]